# t-SQL Aggregate Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate, logical-operators

Lets say we have a table with an ID and a bit column. We execute a query that returns any number of rows (for this example with ID>5). What I want to do is to have an AND aggregate operation across the results of the bit column. I have figured out a workaround, but it's not pretty:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN COUNT(ID) = SUM(CAST(isTrue AS INT)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS areTrue
FROM Table
WHERE ID > 5
```

What I'm doing here, since there is no aggregate function to multiply the results, is practically comparing the total number of records with the sum of the integer representation of the bit column. If they're equal, there are no 'falses', so it works as an AND operation between them.

An OR would be to get the MAX from the column, which is pretty straightforward.

The only problem is that this is particularly ugly and should be killed with fire.
Is there any elegant, proper, way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using a variable to store the calculation,  for example:

```
Declare @result bit = 1

SELECT @result = @result & isTrue 
FROM Table
WHERE ID > 5
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do logic on the bits, how about:

```
select max(cast(isTrue as int)) as AnyTrue,
       min(cast(isTrue as int)) as AllTrue,
       max(1 - cast(isTrue as int)) as AnyFalse,
       min(1 - cast(isTrue as int)) as AllFalse
```

Comment: That's actually pretty nice. You got rid of the COUNT(), but it's still a workaround and you'd also have to CAST back to bit, rather than a proper solution. Isn't there a way to literally DO the logic? It seems weird to me that I don't seem to find a simple, straightforward way of doing this, and even weirder that I haven't come across this issue all these years. You have to agree, it's pretty fundamental.

Comment: @ChrisDane . .. Bit manipulation is not really the realm of relational databases.  What might seem obvious in a procedural language is not necessarily obvious functionality in SQL -- any more than I would expect java to support an out-of-memory hash based join algorithm.  That said, I do think that `min()` and `max()` should work on all datatypes.  The failure to work on bits does stand out.